# Script location tab is empty in Glue Job

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

I'm trying to run the cloudformation template which has GlueJOB resource to create. GlueJob picks the python script from s3 bucket which is in ohio region using scriptlocation command. Template and the python scripts works perfectly fine in ohio region . If the same cloudformation template is used in any other region, cloudformation template is creating all the resources but when i check the AWS management console i'm not seeing the data from python script under script  tab of Glue Job. How can this be resolved , how can i make this python script available to all the regions when i run the cloudformation template?

I have also included the snip for the reference
[Glueissue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9CqZ.png)

Comment: you need to have script present in the same region as you are using Glue